# Labels(tkinter) in python, how can I update the value of a Label and then display it, without showing the previous values of that label?

Tags: python, tkinter, object-oriented-analysis

So, I have this code, and it calculates an OTP(value) each time I click on Button(OTP), and that value is showed on myLabel. However, when it is displayed the values are getting accumulated, E.g. if I click on Button 10 times I will see 10 values on the WINDOW, but I dont want that, I want myLabel shows only one value each time I click on Button, that means I want it to get updated without showing the previous values.
I am attaching an example of what I am getting, in the image it is shown 7 values for myLabel,because I click on Button 7 times, but, instead I want only one value to be shown per each time I click on button.

what can I add to get the result I am aiming for?

```
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib

root=Tk()
root.title("Client")
root.geometry("200x500")

key="800070FF00FF08012"
key=bytes(key,'utf-8')
x=0
def button_click():  
    global x
    global key
    x +=1
    msg=bytes(f'{x}','utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(key, msg,"sha256").digest()
    key=key.replace(key,digest)

    offset = digest[19] & 0xF
    code = digest[offset : offset + 4]
    code = int.from_bytes(code, "big") & 0x7FFFFFFF
    code = code % 1000000
    code="{:06d}".format(code)    

    myLabel=Label(root, text=code).........................> OUTPUT, this is the value that is changing each time I click on Button.
    myLabel.pack()
    

OTP=Button(root,text="Generate OTP",padx=40,pady=20,command=button_click)
OTP.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It is in the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is creating a new label widget every time you click the button.

Instead create the label outside of the function and update the text only when the function runs.   For example:

```
from tkinter import *
import hmac
import hashlib

root=Tk()
root.title("Client")
root.geometry("200x500")

key="800070FF00FF08012"
key=bytes(key,'utf-8')
x=0

def button_click():
    global x
    global key
    x += 1 
    msg=bytes(f'{x}','utf-8')
    digest = hmac.new(key, msg,"sha256").digest()
    key=key.replace(key,digest)
    offset = digest[19] & 0xF
    code = digest[offset : offset + 4]
    code = int.from_bytes(code, "big") & 0x7FFFFFFF
    code = code % 1000000
    code="{:06d}".format(code)
    myLabel.configure(text=code)

myLabel=Label(root, text='')
OTP=Button(root,text="Generate OTP",padx=40,pady=20,command=button_click)
OTP.pack()
myLabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```